# Django REST Framework: Disable migration of all built in schemas, i.e., (auth. contenttypes. admin., etc.)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to disable migrations for all built in schemas, i.e., auth., contenttypes. admin., etc. I'm not using any of these and they really slow down testing. Is it possible to easily disable migrations for these schemas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't using an app, it is perfectly acceptable to remove it from your INSTALLED_APPS in your projects's `settings.py`. This is what I have, and I don't have unused apps clogging my migration history.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'my_app_name_redacted',
]
```

If you are using it, you need to do the migrations for them to work properly.

Incidentally, if you want to *only* migrate for a specific app, but keep them installed so you can later, you can add the app name in the `manage.py migrate` command.

```
python manage.py makemigrations my_app_name_redacted
python manage.py migrate my_app_name_redacted
```